# URL of file-download link

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, firebug, download

I am downloading a file from a location. I would like to get the download link of the file that's being downloaded. I want to save the link in a text file and then later use that link from other places to directly download the object. I am currently working on Firefox, but a generalized approach would be appreciated. Is there a way to do this? I tried JSOUP and I didn't succeed since it was generic to all the external links.

Answer (score 1):

Often times downloaded files do not have source links. For example, say you click a "download" button on a website - it could easily send POST data to a form on a 'download.php' page something like this:

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 

    readfile($_POST['file']);
?>
```

Comment: Whenever a download is initiated from a webpage, is it possible to interject and find out what is being downloaded and the source so that it can be redirected to another machine to be saved there.

Comment: You can always look at Firebug or your Web Developer tools in Chrome and analyze the Network tab. All files transferred to you will show up there and you'll see the origin of the file - but you won't be able to "interject" or send anything upstream.